# Powershell and FTP Upload and renaming

Tags: powershell, command-line, ftp

I have a powershell script that uses system.net.webclient to upload a file to an FTP site. They pther side now requires us to upload the file with a temporary name and then rename it on the FTP server after the upload. How can I do this? The filename is randomized and long- should I include a few steps to add-content to a file and use FTP -s: to run it, or is there a cleaner way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.aspx) rather than Webclient, which has both an `UploadFile` method and a `Rename` method.